# Avoid errors when comparing title field to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, error-handling, compare, title

The following code gets the first word from my page title, compares it to the values of an array and outputs me a final value :

```js
var fulltitle = "Deep Blue Shoes";
var arr = fulltitle.split(' ').slice(0, 1);
var title = arr && arr.length ? arr[0] : "";

//test variables 
testarray = ["blue", "top", "110", "in stock", "deep blue", "down", "111", "in stock"]

//function
function testfunction(array, variable) {
  var varindex = array.indexOf(variable.toLowerCase())
  return array[varindex + 2]
}

//calling the function
var finalvalue = testfunction(testarray, title);

console.log( finalvalue )
```

In this case, if my title is Deep Blue shoes, the system cuts the title too early and try to compare the value 'deep' with the values into the array. But the value deep doesn't exist.

I'm trying to find a solution for this and similiar problems that may occur, since my variables can be like 'blue', 'deep blue', 'deep blue sky'. We work with exact matches only.

How would you fix this ?

See also https://jsfiddle.net/Francesco82/hg10a3wy/

Comment: Is this what you want @francesco? https://jsfiddle.net/alexander_L/gx83mrtL/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem with a trick just by modifing this code at the very beginning

```
var fulltitle = (document.title);
var arr = fulltitle.split(':').slice(0, 1);
```

Since the part of title we need is always before the ':' , in this way I'm able to get the right result without making advanced comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a String (or RegEx) comparison?

But in the first example this matches with both "blue" as well as "deep blue" (and in the second "acquacalda" as well as "acqua").

What logic should we use in those cases? If it matches with more than one, choose the one with the most words if one has more words than the others (i.e., in that case, choose "deep blue") and if the matches are the same number of words choose the longer of the two words? i.e. In the second case choose "acquacalda" over "acqua"? (in general, always choosing the more specific answer)

See below and https://jsfiddle.net/alexander_L/gx83mrtL/3/

```js
findPage("Deep Blue Shoes");
findPage("Acquacalda");

function findPage(fulltitle){
  //test variables 
  const testarray = ["blue", "top", "110", "in stock", "deep blue", "down", "111", "in stock", "acqua", "top", "112", "in stock", "acquacalda", "down", "113", "in stock"]

  const altMatches = testarray.reduce((aggArr, item) => {
    if (fulltitle.toLowerCase().includes(item)){
      console.log('we have a match with ' + item);   
      aggArr.push(item);
    }
    return aggArr;
  }, []);

  //then we can choose the "largest" match:
  const finalMatch = altMatches.reduce((aggMatch, item) => {
    if (aggMatch == null || (aggMatch.split(' ').length < item.split(' ').length) || (aggMatch.length < item.length)){
      return item;
    }
    return aggMatch;
  }, null);

  console.log('the final match is ' + finalMatch);

  const finalPage = testarray.indexOf(finalMatch) + 2;
  console.log('the final match page number is ' + testarray[finalPage]);
}
```

OUTPUT:

```js
"we have a match with blue"
"we have a match with deep blue"
"the final match is deep blue"
"the final match page number is 111"

"we have a match with acqua"
"we have a match with acquacalda"
"the final match is acquacalda"
"the final match page number is 113"
```

Comment: The system shoukd work with exact matches. For example : Blue is a match, deep blue could be another one, very deep blue another one and so one.

Comment: Ok, so given the example input "Deep Blue Shoes" and given your ``testarray`` what do you expect the output to be? I give the output as "deep blue" is that correct? Is my answer already correct? If not please explain how.

Comment: The final match should not be the correct page title, but the value corresponding to the correct page title. The final match of the example should be 111, if you see my code i get it using return array[varindex + 2]. I can't figure out how to implement this in your code so I can't test if it works correctly

Comment: Sorry, can you explain a bit more clearly why the final match should be "111"? That doesn't make sense to me. You just want to always return the value to the right of the match by 2? So since "111" has index 6 we show that because "deep blue" has index 4? Does my updated answer now work as expected?

Comment: Sure : the idea of the script is to get the post title, compare with the array, match the title with the "intermediate" value (deep blue for example) and get the "final value" that is the one two positions after the "intermediate" value.

Comment: I guess it should be a very poor architecture, so maybe there could be a more logic way to collect the data :)

Comment: I'm trying to make it work, but it outputs me "1" as result instead of the expected value

Comment: I confirm, it doesnt work and makes a very strange error.
First try ; Expected value : "-121579" , output value : "12717"
Second try : Expected value : "-131012", output value "23207"
The output values are not even into my array So i can't understand how it collects them :O

Comment: Please can you stick to the example from your question, or include the example you are referencing somewhere? As the expected values you just stated in your comment do not match your question? My current answer outputs “111” click “Run code snippet” and you can see this in the console?

Comment: Alex your code doesn't work. I mean, it works with the three values in the example, but it does not work always. I'm going to post an example

Comment: Yeah please post an example because I don't have the data you are referring to :) - When you post this, then I can try to see why it doesn't always work.

Comment: Sorry I can't post the code but just try to use Acquacalda as title and acqua and acquacalda into the array and you will see the error. I just tested it on JSFiddle you can see it here : https://jsfiddle.net/Francesco82/hg10a3wy/

Comment: See updated answer and fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/alexander_L/gx83mrtL/3/ - does that work?